# How to make key-value pair from database

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table in MySQL database with columns id and name. My question is: how to make key-value pair for possible values in select field on form (this is for practice PHP in NetBeans). When I fetch all from the table, this is print_r (for one):

```
 [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [0] => 5
            [name] => Newest
            [1] => Newest
        )
```

How to make key-value pair id => name;

Answer (score 1):

This might help...

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "dbName";
    
    
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM tableName');
    $stmt->execute();
    
    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    print_r($stmt->fetchAll());
```